# How to overcome failures while doing UI Automation for Knockout Web sites

Tags: c#, ajax, testing, selenium-webdriver, knockout.js

I'm working on knockout based site using selenium web driver + c# to automate. My test methods fail because of elements not found / not able to click as the site is slow / or the binding/ rendering of html is slow after the ajax calls are finished.

Below is sample code I used to know the ajax calls have finished and I can proceed to search elements.

```
public static void waitForAjax(IWebDriver driver, String action)
{
    try
    {
        TimeSpan tp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(tp);
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteAsyncScript(
            "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
            "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
            "xhr.open('GET', '/" + action + "', true);" +
            "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
            "  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {" +
            "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
            "  }" +
            "};" +
            "xhr.send();");
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I am calling the above method before going to find the elements.

Test Method

```
try
{
     IWebDriver _Driver;
     IWebElement ele;
     FirefoxDriverService _Service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"D:\CodePlex_C#\SeleniumTestWithHtml\SeleniumTestWithHtml\Drivers");
     _Driver = new FirefoxDriver(_Service);
     _Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("HomepageURl");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call1");
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call2");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
     ele = _Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("DASHBOARD"));
     ele.Click();
     //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call1");
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call2");
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call3");
     waitForAjax(_Driver,"Call4");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
     ele = _Driver.FindElement(By.Id("QuickSearchCnt"));
     ele.Click();
}
```

But my Code Fails. I suspect the code to find the calls have finished to execute is not working properly.

I need help in knowing is my approach right? And need help in fixing the issue.